# encoding when get page from net

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding

I need to download a webpage, I have the following code to determe the encoding

```
                System.IO.StreamReader sr=null;

                mFrm.InfoShotcut("Henter webside....");
                if(response.ContentEncoding!=null && response.ContentEncoding!="")
                {
                    sr=new System.IO.StreamReader(srm,System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(response.ContentEncoding));
                }
                else
                {
                    //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show();
                    sr=new  System.IO.StreamReader(srm,System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
                }

                if(sr!=null)
                {
                    result=sr.ReadToEnd();

                     if(response.CharacterSet!=GetCharatset(result))
                    {
                        System.Text.Encoding CorrectEncoding=System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(GetCharatset(result));

                        HttpWebRequest client2=(HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Helper.value1);

                        HttpWebResponse response2=(HttpWebResponse)client2.GetResponse();

                        System.IO.Stream srm2=response2.GetResponseStream();

                        sr=new System.IO.StreamReader(srm2,CorrectEncoding);

                        result=sr.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }

                mFrm.InfoShotcut("Henter webside......");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // handle error
                MessageBox.Show( ex.Message );
            }
```

And it had worked great, but now i have tried it with a site, where it states it uses

```
<pre>
&lt;META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</pre>
```

But realy is in UTF-8, how do I find out that sow i can save the file with the right encoding.

Comment: There are a lof of sites like that. You have to find a way to `guess` the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the `Content-Encoding` header does not describe the character set being used. As the [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.5) says:

> Content codings are primarily used to allow a document to be compressed or otherwise usefully transformed without losing the identity of its underlying media type and without loss of information.

The character set used is described in the `Content-Type` header. For example:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Your code above that uses the `Content-Encoding` header will not correctly identify the character set. You have to look at the `Content-Type` header, find the semicolon if it's there, and then parse the `charset` parameter.

And, as you've discovered, it can also be described in an HTML `META` tag.

Or, there might not be a character set definition at all, in which case you have to default to something. My experience has been that defaulting to UTF-8 is a good choice. It's not 100% reliable, but it seems that sites that don't include the `charset` parameter with the `Content-Type` field *usually* default to UTF-8. I've also found that `META` tags, when they exist, are wrong almost half the time.

As L.B mentioned in his comment, it's possible to download the bytes and examine them to determine the encoding. That can be done with a surprising degree of accuracy, but it requires a lot of code.